# Yii 2.0 enabling remote access to gii

Tags: yii2

Simple question, trying to enable remote access to gii in yii 2 - docs say http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

```
Note: If you are accessing Gii from a machine other than localhost, the access will be denied by default for security purpose. You can configure Gii to add the allowed IP addresses as follows,

'gii' => [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*', '192.168.178.20'] // adjust this to your needs
],
```

Thing is, it doesn't say where to add this - guesing config/web.php

But under what section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 places you need to add this.

Usually it is done like this in your main-local.php

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];   
}
```

So you need to add gii in the bootstrap section of the config and in the modules section. This will turn basically append them to the array from your config/main.php
return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(**DIR**),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        ],
    ],

On the link you gave, take a look above. You should do:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*', '192.168.178.20'] // adjust this to your needs
];
}
```

Comment: I have this in config/web.php
`if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}`

Comment: Thanks - confused me the original didn't have the `class => ..` That worked